# Cancel Y axis touch move in slider to scroll down pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to cancel a touch move in the y axis with pure JavaScript, I try to search on everywere, but any solution is working.
The site is working in this domaing: [Site](https://lucasbonato.github.io)

```
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider-container'),
  slides = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.slide'))

// set up our state
let isDragging = false,
  startPos = 0,
  currentTranslate = 0,
  prevTranslate = 0,
  animationID,
  currentIndex = 0

// add our event listeners
slides.forEach((slide, index) => {
  const slideImage = slide.querySelector('img')
  // disable default image drag
  slideImage.addEventListener('dragstart', (e) => e.preventDefault())
  if(slides.length >= 2) {
    // pointer events
    slide.addEventListener('touchstart', touchStart(index))
    slide.addEventListener('touchend', touchEnd)
    slide.addEventListener('touchmove', touchMove)
    // mouse events
    slide.addEventListener('mousedown', touchStart(index))
    slide.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp)
    slide.addEventListener('mousemove', touchMove)
    slide.addEventListener('mouseleave', mouseLeave)
  }
})

// make responsive to viewport changes
window.addEventListener('resize', setPositionByIndex)

// use a HOF so we have index in a closure
function getPositionX(event) {
  return event.type.includes('mouse') ? event.pageX : event.touches[0].clientX
}

function goPrev(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  event.stopPropagation()
  if (currentIndex > 0) {
    currentIndex -= 1
    setPositionByIndex()
  }
  return false
}

function goNext(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  event.stopPropagation()
  if (currentIndex < slides.length - 1) {
    currentIndex += 1
    setPositionByIndex()
  }
  return false
}

// use a HOF so we have index in a closure
function touchStart(index) {
  return function (event) {
    currentIndex = index
    startPos = getPositionX(event)
    isDragging = true
    animationID = requestAnimationFrame(animation)
    slider.classList.add('grabbing')
  }
}

function touchMove(event) {
  if (isDragging) {
    const currentPosition = getPositionX(event)
    currentTranslate = prevTranslate + currentPosition - startPos
  }
}

function touchEnd() {
  endGrab()
  setPositionByIndex()
}

function mouseUp() {
  endGrab()
  setPositionByIndex()
}

function mouseLeave() {
  endGrab()
}

function endGrab() {
  cancelAnimationFrame(animationID)
  isDragging = false
  const movedBy = currentTranslate - prevTranslate

  // if moved enough negative then snap to next slide if there is one
  if (movedBy < -50 && currentIndex < slides.length - 1) {
    currentIndex += 1
  }

  // if moved enough positive then snap to previous slide if there is one
  if (movedBy > 50 && currentIndex > 0) {
    currentIndex -= 1
  }

  slider.classList.remove('grabbing')
}

function animation() {
  setSliderPosition()
  if (isDragging) requestAnimationFrame(animation)
}

function setPositionByIndex() {
  currentTranslate = currentIndex * -window.innerWidth
  prevTranslate = currentTranslate

  setSliderPosition()
}

function setSliderPosition() {
  slider.style.transform = `translateX(${currentTranslate}px)`
}
```

I appreciate any answer.

---

I tried this two solutions in JS and a few more I cannot find sorry.

attempt number one:

```
const element = document.querySelector('.slider-container');

let startY;

element.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
  startY = event.touches[0].clientY;
});

element.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
  const currentY = event.touches[0].clientY;
  const deltaY = currentY - startY;

  if (Math.abs(deltaY) > Math.abs(event.touches[0].clientX - event.touches[0].clientY)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

attemp number two:

```
const element = document.querySelector('.slider-container');

element.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
  const deltaY = event.touches[0].clientY - event.touches[0].pageY;
  if (Math.abs(deltaY) > 10) {
    event.preventDefault();
    element.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
    setTimeout(function() {
      element.style.overflowY = '';
    }, 100);
  }
});
```

The objetive of this is to scroll down when someone touch scroll down to go bellow the slider.